# SQL Server procedure - Merge two tables without duplicates - if table B column B =1 then

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, left-join

I am trying to Merge two tables in SQL with no duplicates. I need the values of Table B column B to be selected if the values=1. Table A is a list box containing the default values and table B holds the list box values per user.

Table A

```
Col_A  Col_B
------------
701     null
702     null
703     null
704     null
```

Table B

```
Col_A  Col_B
-------------
701    1
703    1
```

Desired result

```
Col_A  Col_B
-------------
701    1
702    null
703    1
704    null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want a  `left join`?

```
select a.col_a, b.col_b
from table_a a
left join table_b b on b.col_a = a.col_a
```

> I need the values of Table B column B to be selected if the values=1

In your sample data, all rows in table b have value `1`. If you do want to filter on the value as well, then add another condition to the `left join`:

```
select a.col_a, b.col_b
from table_a a
left join table_b b on b.col_a = a.col_a and b.col_b = 1
```

With these two columns only, this does not seem very helful though. If you just want to know if *some row* exists in table b with the same `col_a` and a value of `1`, then `exists` is more appropriate:

```
select a.col_a,
    case when exists (select 1 from tableb b where b.col_a = a.col_a and b.col_b = 1)
        then 1
    end as col_b
from table_a a
```

Comment: I tried the first 2 along with unions but neither worked. Your last example worked great! I wanted to merge the two based on Table A  and have no repeats. Sorry if that was not clearer but you got it! I will study this.